# web.config set UseSSL false

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, iis-8

I am getting deep trouble for by just changing web.config content. After so many traces, I have found that it causes because I have changed web.config.

When I change my web.config file, UseSSL parameter get "False". This cause so many issues like Payment Gateway.

Can anybody suggest me which thing make it false?

Following are new element that is not there in old web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" optimizeCompilations="true" enablePrefetchOptimization="true">
          <assemblies>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" pageParserFilterType="BVSoftware.Bvc5.Core.Utilities.BVPageParserFilter">

        <authentication mode="None"/>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
          <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="FirstDataGlobalGatewayE4">
              <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="https://api.xxxxxxxxxx.firstdata.com/transaction/v11"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FirstDataGlobalGatewayE4"
                    contract="FirstDataService.ServiceSoap" name="FirstDataGlobalGatewayE4" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What issues exactly? Build errors? Runtime errors? Why would you want to support cookies over an insecure link?

Comment: @Crowcoder I am not good in web.config. I just put as it is as it was given by CMS providers. Can you suggest me if something stopping or anything need to change. I will change accordingly and try. Please guide.

Comment: @Crowcoder Issue found in SagePay redirect URL. If I don't keep new changes, my SagePay works properly. If I add above content, it returns 5006 error that says either redirect URL is not proper or the vendor doesn't provide "OK" status.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help, sounds like you need to talk to SagePay support.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks. I have talk with them. They have sent me 2 comments. `1- Clear the response buffer to remove any header code, comments or HTML.` `2- The NotificationURL should ONLY respond with a Status field, a RedirectURL field and optionally a StatusDetail field.` Can you please review above comment from SagePay and let me know if anything from web.config stops?

Comment: I would not suspect the web.config to be the problem based on those comments.